# Spark seems to be installed but can't import pyspark module

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My `pip install pyspark` worked, I get a message in my command prompt that SparkSession available as 'spark'.

However, when I do:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

it gives me a:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: you need to set SPARK_HOME  and PYTHONPATH variables set

Comment: Thanks, and how do I do that?

Comment: are you on linux or windows ? do you know the path to the spark directory?

Answer (score 1):

You should install findspark modeule by pip then try:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('<your spark home directory for example /home/spark>')
```

then you can import spark modules.